# Android Studio | Flamingo doesn't update

Tags: linux, android-studio

Icon for updates on start screen in Android Studio (Flamingo) not clickable on Linux, look
at the screenshot:

[image: Icon no clickable]

I tried to update from setting, there update downloading, but nothing happens:

[image: In settings]

Is it known issue? Do you have the same problem?

Comment: I have the same issue on macOS. My current installed version is Flamingo 2022.2.1. My work laptop (Windows 10) has the same issue as well.

Using the JetBrains toolbox updated my install, but it seems to have installed it separately, because I can launch 2 different versions. Hitting uninstall from the JetBrains toolbox removed my manual installation.

Comment: I had the same issue on Linux. Have you made any progress?

Comment: No, could anybody somehow say about this problem to devs?

Comment: same problem on macOS Ventura, but it works fine on macOS Montarey.

Comment: For macOS just download the latest DMG from https://developer.android.com/studio and replace the existing app. You won't lose the local settings.

Comment: Same issue on Windows 10 19045.3208 and Android Studio 2022.2.1 Patch 2.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1.